# Architecture Design: REST vs WebSockets

Tags: node.js, rest, ionic-framework, websocket, architecture

a friend and I am currently working on a mobile app with Ionic and NodeJs. On the one hand we want to implement functionality like a todo and a shopping list, on the other hand we want  to add a live chat with all that typical stuff.

We‘re are asking ourselves what kind of architecture to use. Do we use REST or WebSockets or both? Does it make sense to implement two Node servers (one REST, one WebSocket)?

Thanks!

Comment: Implementing both will serve the purpose.

Comment: You can use both in same server. For chatting use `Socket.io` and for other stuff use REST apis.

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you for your help. So it‘s best practice to use both for the according use case. That sounds reasonable.

Comment: Both..... but be careful. My advice use Micro Services to deliver a better experience. If you design your app to have say a  separate "todo" and "my shopping list" as separate Micro Services, this will help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, we just decided to go with microservice architecture.